# Outlook for Mac - Missing ribbons

Tags: email, ms-office

Today I was about to send an email when I've noticed that on the Compose screen most ribbons were missing. Ribbons like 'Insert', 'Table' (IIRC), were just not there. All I got was a super simple compose window with a handful of formatting options.

Do you know how can I re enable all the lost formatting tools?

*Current Compose Window, note how many formatting options are not present*
[image: Current Window]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To add the Ribbon on/off to your Tool bar right click on it and select "Customize Toolbar".

In the new window, drag the Ribbon to your Tool bar.

[image: ribbon]

The ribbon you are showing is already the standard version on MS Outlook 2011.

It can not be further customized, unlike the other MS office products.